# ssrs printing of reports

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

I have 2 tables first table is of size letter (11 inches * 8.5 inches) second table is greater than this in width . When i render this tables to excel sheet i see extra column in first worksheet for first table. I think this is because while rendering the reports all worksheet is rendered to same width. Because of this extra column in worksheet 1 i get extra pages  with header and footer on that how can i remove that extra pages can i have to manually remove that column each time before printing from worksheet 1 that makes size of report beyond page width 11 inches.

thank you

Comment: There are few reasons for incorrect rendering, but the most common issue is related to the alignment of the headers, footers and content. Make sure that all these have the same width.

Comment: hello kiril thanks for your reply... actually when i remove the second table the worksheet 1 automatically  goes to correct size and now the extra column is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is a common issue with regards to SSRS rendering to different formats. For example if you want your report to look decent in PDF output you need to get the correct dimensions that is specific to PDF or in your case EXCEL. If your report (table, list, matrix etc.) goes slightly over this dimension then you will get an extra page as you mention in your question.

You need to fit your table in the required dimensions that is suitable for that specific format, this will get rid of the extra page when printing.

For PDF this is more straight forward because if it fits on the PDF it will print accordingly. Excel on the other hand is easy to format for but printing is handled differently.

I have the exact dimensions for PDF which i will update my post with. For excel printing though you will need to play around with your report to see what the most suitable dimensions is for excel printing...keeping in mind that the report needs to readable in a digital format.